# How to make Admin categories available for users when creating an idea

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and right now I'm working on building and Idea Box.
ONLY Admin can create categories. 
Users can crud their ideas. 
Authorization is working so far. 
**Problem: When a user fills in the form to create an idea they should see a selection dropdown for choosing a category.

I can't make it available for the user to see the categories. 
category_id is in the schema.

form for creating an idea

```
    <%= form_for(@user, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
      <div class="field form-group">
        <%= f.label :username,  class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'%>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field form-group">
        <%= f.label :category_id, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @category, :id, :title, :required => true, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :password, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actions form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-success' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170529152548) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "ideas", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_ideas_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.integer "role", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "email"
  end

  add_foreign_key "ideas", "users"
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  has_many :ideas
  has_many :categories, source: :ideas

  enum role: ['default', 'admin']

end
```

Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_many :ideas

end
```

Idea.rb

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

end
```

I tried to use `has_many :categories, source: :ideas`  no good results. 
If anyone can help,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why is that, are you getting an error or something?

Comment: You say "I can't make it available for the user to see the categories", do you mean just in the view? Can you do this manually in `rails c`? Your DB code looks good, and if this is a view thing then you should really include your controller code. Can't help debug a view helper that depends on data I can't see being assigned.

Comment: I was able to render in the view by changing a line in the form       ` <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: true %>`
but now i can't make an idea, something got messed up in the controller.. which i just added